3D Geometry Extrusion Algorithm

I have a plane which has A, B, C, D 3d points, which faces upwards ( normal ). When I extrude the plane it create a new plane which duplicates the face since the four vertices already connected and creates a new face A1, B1, C1, D1. and it also has same normal. When I try to create the side faces the face orientation changed the direction of the face is not correct so the editor culls the face. I can disable culling but I want the side face normal to be correct, so I can draw clockwise triangle.
I tried some methods like using Cross product and some other stuff I also tried to get some book or document related to this algorithm but I didn't get any. So is there is any way to draw side faces with perfect normal and clockwise triangle. I know once the triangle is drawn correctly in clockwise the normal can be recalculated. If you have any docs or book it would help a lot.

You were one the right track with using cross product. To be able to calculate the normal of a triangle you need to find 2 vectors that are parallel to your triangle and then find the cross product of that. As you can see in the image below if we have k and v we can find the normal (v x k):

So step number one is to find the 2 parallel vectors. If you have the 3 vectors of a triangle v1, v2 and v3, you can calculate the 2 parallel vectors by finding the difference between 2 of those points. These parallel vectors (lets call them p1 and p2) are essentially the sides of the triangle. However, the order of subtraction does matter because the resulting normal can be either forward or backwards facing depending.
The way I found that works is: p1 = v1 - v2, p2 = v3 - v2.
See the diagram below:

Now you can calculate the cross product of those vectors to find the normal.

Also make sure you normalize your normal vector!
Check out this page for some useful vector knowledge specifically related to 3d graphics.
And this site has a decent 3d vector plotter for visualizing vector math.
